# Error when link 2 table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, alter-table

I am trying to link 2 table in sql server let's assume one of them called `customer` and the other is `product`.

`customer` has `custID` as primary key and i want to link it with `custID` in `product` table as foreign key, and its give me this error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_product_customer". The conflict occurred in database "xyz", table "dbo.customer", column 'custID #'.

Is there anyone know, how can I fix the issue?

Comment: Are column types equal?

Comment: yes both of them is numeric

Comment: Check if there are values of custID in product that are not in customer.

Comment: i'm not using code to link i just use ui on sql server this is my steps: 1. i go to product table 2. i choose design 3. i go to column custID and click right and choose relationship , after that i add the link between them

Comment: yeah there is , is that will cause problem?

Comment: Yes. You should add these customer ids in customer table. The main purpose of foreign keys is to avoid such situations. Every value of cust id in product must have corresponding value in customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could have many reasons.

1. Do you have a type missmatch between those columns?
2. Is every customer in products also in your customer table?

You can check the second part by using this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.customer_id
FROM products as p
LEFT JOIN customers as c ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE c.customer_id is null
```

Hope this give you a hint.

Comment: 1. No they are of the same type , but the second question is yes , when i execute the query i got some result , what should i do?

Comment: You have just two options. Remove the rows from the product table as they have no mapped customer. Or create a customer and map those rows to the newly created customer. Afterwards create your foreign key.

Comment: No problem. Did this work for you? If so, you can mark the answer as your solution. (I see that your a new user :))